# Ensuring integral result from integral linear program

Tags: linear-programming

An [integral linear program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming#Integral_linear_programs) is one that has a maximizer that is integral. Sometimes it's possible to prove that a particular LP has this property, for example by proving that it's constraint matrix is [totally unimodular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unimodular_matrix#Total_unimodularity).

Suppose that we have an integral LP, how can we then efficiently find an integral maximizer? After all, the optimum may be achieved by many different maximizers rather than just the integral ones.

Comment: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/47280/5038

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was cross-posted and answered elsewhere.